# Tikzpicture Package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem in my code of my thesis  as show in this figure [image]

the code is

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=4em, row sep=6ex, inner sep=pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
     & \node[mypoint, label={above:v$_{1}$}] (V1) {}; 
    &  &   \node[mypoint, label={left:v$_{2}$}] (V2) {}; \\
    \\
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]v$_{4}$}] (V4) {}; & &  \node[mypoint, label={[above,xshift=2pt]v$_{3}$}] (V3) {};\\
};

\draw (V4) --node[above]{e$_{3}$}  (V3);
\draw (V4) -- node[left]{e$_{5}$} (V1);
\draw (V2) -- node[left]{e$_{2}$} (V3);
\draw (V1) -- node[right]{e$_{1}$}(V3);

\draw (V4) to [bend right] node[below]{e$_{4}$} (V3);
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{A graph for walks\label{6}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In the matrix options (line 325 in the screen shot) there is a value missing for `inner sep`. You have to add a number between `inner sep=` and `pt`.

Comment: I added 0 as number, also i try to put 1 as number but the erorr are still

Comment: What is the definition of `mypoint/.style`? May be there is a value missing, too.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

I think that you probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mypoint/.style={circle, radius=1mm, fill=black}]
    \matrix[column sep=4em, row sep=6ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
         & \node[mypoint, label={above:v$_{1}$}] (V1) {};
        &  &   \node[mypoint, label={left:v$_{2}$}] (V2) {}; \\
        \\
        \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]v$_{4}$}] (V4) {}; & &  \node[mypoint, label={[above,xshift=2pt]v$_{3}$}] (V3) {};\\
    };

    \draw (V4) --node[above]{e$_{3}$}  (V3);
    \draw (V4) -- node[left]{e$_{5}$} (V1);
    \draw (V2) -- node[left]{e$_{2}$} (V3);
    \draw (V1) -- node[right]{e$_{1}$}(V3);

    \draw (V4) to [bend right] node[below]{e$_{4}$} (V3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As noted above, you were missing a unit for the `inner sep` and a style definition for `mypoint`. I used `inner sep=0pt` and `mypoint/.style={circle, radius=1mm, fill=black}`. This produces:

[image]

Another other possibility is put the lines

```
\tikzset{
   mypoint/.style={circle, radius=1mm, fill=black}
}
```

somewhere at the top of your document so that you can use the `mypoint` style in any `tikzpicture` environment.

Btw, when asking questions rather  than  giving a screenshot and a fragment of code it is much better if you give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be a complete piece of compilable code, like the code that I have posted above, that is as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.